# Javascript Currencie convertor

Tags: javascript, parsing, object

I have this object :

```
{"keys":Number,
 "metal":Number}
```

I know that one key = 37 metals. So, If I have:

```
{"keys" = 0,
 "metal" = 42}
```

I need a function that can convert this to correct format that should be:

```
{"keys" = 1,
 "metal"= 5}
```

What I have tried :

```
Methods.prototype.parseToCorrect = function(priceObj) {
var newTotal = {
    metal: Number,
    keys: Number
}
var decimals = priceObj.keys - Math.floor(priceObj.keys);

if (decimals !== 0) {
    var decimalPlaces = priceObj.keys.toString().split('.')[1].length;
    decimals = decimals.toFixed(decimalPlaces);
    var toRef = decimals * 37;
    newTotal.metal = toRef + priceObj.metal;
    newTotal.keys = priceObj.keys - decimals;
    var moreThanKey = newTotal.metal / 37;
    if (moreThanKey > 1) {
        newTotal.metal -= Math.floor(moreThanKey) * 37;
        newTotal.keys += Math.floor(moreThanKey);
    }
    return newTotal;
} else {
  var moreThanKey = priceObj.metal /37;
  if (moreThanKey > 1) {
      newTotal.metal -= Math.floor(moreThanKey) * 37;
      newTotal.keys += Math.floor(moreThanKey);
  }
    newTotal.metal = priceObj.metal;
    newTotal.keys = priceObj.keys;
    return newTotal;
}
```

}

Explanation : 
if(decimals !== 0) means that piceObj parsed is like : (down). And I need that "keys" be INTEGER

```
{"keys"=0.5,
 "metal" = 13}
```

So, my function is working fine. But I think it should exists a better way? Thanks in advance

Comment: currency is an object. object.map exists? I understand that no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece you're missing is truncating the decimal places, which can be done with `Number.trunc()`.  The following performs the conversion you wanted for this one very limited scenario.

```js
function conversion(original) {
    var metal = original.keys * 37 + original.metal;
    return { keys: Math.trunc(metal/37)
           , metal: metal%37
           }
}

console.log( conversion({ keys: 0, metal: 42 }) )
console.log( conversion({ keys: 0.5, metal: 0 }) )
```

Comment: Thanks. But converted.keys should be integer. So If I have original.keys = 0.5 and original.metal = 0; I need to parse it to original.keys = 0 and original.metal = 18.5

Comment: The pieces you needed were there.  It's trivial to adapt the code to solve that, but updated anyway